# How to change "Billing details" title on WooCommerce checkout page with a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to change some titles on the WooCommerce checkout page.

One of the titles is "Billing details"

I've tried:

```php
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Billing details' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Billing Info', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```

I just can't change the text of those, whatever I add to my functions.php or WooCommerce alterations file.

Can you please let me know, how I can change those title?

**Note:** I would like to make use of action hooks. I don't won't to copy the WooCommerce template file as other options suggests.

Comment: Have you checked if your theme is over ruling the default template ? `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php` the method you mentioned should work when using the default Woocommerce template as line 23 of that file is as follows `<h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>` the function `esc_html_e` uses `gettext`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. But I'm not making use of my own template files to override those of Woocommerce. All I'm doing to customize my theme, is by the usage of action hooks.

Comment: in that case the method you used with gettext should work just fine, can you try switching on `$text` instead ? and try with a higher priority 99 instead of 20 for example

Comment: @ThomasTromp are you sure you adding in your active theme functions.php file? because I just tested and working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `switch ( $translated_text ) {` with `switch ( $text ) {` in your code.
This is because `$text` contains the original (undertranslated) text while `$translated_text` contains... the name of the variable already indicates it.

---

Or use

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $original_text, $domain ) {   
    // Is admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $translated;
    
    // No match
    if ( $original_text != 'Billing details' ) return $translated;
    
    // Match
    $translated = __( 'Billing Info', $domain );
    
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```